# ¿Cómo uso los en una consulta SQL con la cláusula LIKE?

Tags: c#, sql

Estoy haciendo una aplicación del tipo Windows Forms y tengo un problema con los parámetros de la consulta. Estoy creando un sistema de búsqueda donde se escribe en un formulario el nombre o apellido de una persona, se le da clic al botón para buscar y luego se crean etiquetas con el nombre de la personas encontradas.

Ya casi lo he hecho. El problema es que la consulta me regresa **todos** los nombres de la base de datos. Aquí dejo el código:

```
conexion.Open();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
datos.Nombre = txtNomDoc.Text;
datos.APaterno = txtApellido.Text;
datos.AMaterno = datos.APaterno;

SqlCommand teacherQuery = new SqlCommand("SELECT Nombre FROM MAESTROS WHERE " +
"Nombre LIKE @Nombre OR " +
"Paterno LIKE @Paterno OR " +
"Materno LIKE @Materno;", conexion);

teacherQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", "%" + datos.Nombre + "%");
teacherQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Paterno", "%" + datos.APaterno + "%");
teacherQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Materno", "%" + datos.AMaterno + "%");

MessageBox.Show(datos.Nombre, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
MessageBox.Show(datos.APaterno, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
MessageBox.Show(datos.AMaterno, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(teacherQuery);
da.Fill(dt);

int noRows = dt.Rows.Count;
MessageBox.Show(noRows.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

for (int i = 0; i < noRows; i++)
{
    Label lblDocente = new Label();
    lblDocente.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Nombre"].ToString();
    flpResultados.Controls.Add(lblDocente);
}
```

Ya estuve buscando maneras de hacer esta consulta, pero obtengo el mismo resultado con estos formatos:

```
SqlCommand teacherQuery = new SqlCommand("SELECT Nombre FROM MAESTROS WHERE " + 
"(Nombre LIKE concat('%',@Nombre,'%')) OR " +
"(Paterno LIKE concat('%',@Paterno,'%'))  OR " +
"(Materno LIKE concat('%',@Materno,'%'));", conexion);

SqlCommand teacherQuery = new SqlCommand("SELECT Nombre FROM MAESTROS WHERE " +
"(Nombre LIKE '%' + @Nombre + '%' OR " +
"Paterno LIKE '%' + @Paterno + '%' OR " +
"Materno LIKE '%' + @Materno + '%');", conexion);
```

De esta forma, el *dt.Rows.Count* me regresa 0:

```
SqlCommand teacherQuery = new SqlCommand("select Nombre from MAESTROS where " +
"(Nombre=@Nombre or " +
"Paterno=@Paterno or " +
"Materno=@Materno);", conexion);
```

Y de esta manera, siempre me regresa 2:

```
SqlCommand teacherQuery = new SqlCommand("SELECT Nombre FROM MAESTROS WHERE " +
"Nombre LIKE '%@Nombre%' or " +
"Paterno LIKE '%@Paterno%' or " +
"Materno LIKE'%@Materno%';", conexion);
```

Ya intenté en el *addWithValue* concaternar los *%*, o poner sólo la variable, pero obtengo los mismos resultados. Pienso debe ser problema de estos mismos signos, porque si hago consultas estáticas o los quito, si consigo lo que quiero lograr. ¿Piensan que pudiera ser otra cosa o algún problema con mi cadena de conexión?

Muchas gracias. Soy nueva programando en C#, disculpen las molestias.

Comment: Intenta algo como    SqlCommand teacherQuery = new SqlCommand("SELECT Nombre FROM MAESTROS WHERE Nombre LIKE '%" + datos.Nombre + "%' OR Paterno LIKE '%" + datos.NomAPaternobre + "%' OR Materno LIKE '%" + datos.AMaterno + "%';", conexion);   y elimina de tu codigo los 3 teacherQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue...

Comment: @Anyel Ya lo intenté, y me ocurre lo mismo. Me regresa 17, que son todos los datos de mi tabla.

Comment: @Nohemi el problema son los or tienes que usar () para encerrarlo

Comment: ¿Encerrando (Nombre LIKE...) or (Paterno LIKE...)? Así me siguen saliendo todos los datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nohemi, el problema que tienes es más de la lógica de la consulta.   Si alguno de los parámetros está vacío, tu consulta quedaría con el like % y esto te retorna todos los resultados.   Por ejemplo:

```
Nombre = "Daniel";
Paterno = "";
Materno = "";
```

Tu query quedaría así:

```
SELECT Nombre 
  FROM Maestros
 WHERE Nombre like '%Daniel%'
    OR Paterno like '%%'
    OR Materno like '%%'
```

En este caso, como la consulta es con OR y con el %, te regresaría todos los registros.

Solución 1:
Generar todo el query dinámicamente desde C#:

```
var query = "select nombre from maestros";
var where = " where 1=1 ";
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(datos.Nombre)){
   where += " and Nombre like '%" + datos.Nombre + "%'"
}
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(datos.APaterno)){
   where += " and Paterno like '%" + datos.APaterno+ "%'"
}
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(datos.AMaterno)){
   where += " and Materno like '%" + datos.AMaterno+ "%'"
}

SqlCommand teacherQuery = new SqlCommand(query + where, conexion);
```

El problema de esta solución es el SQL-Injection que te pueden hacer.

Solución 2: 
Que tu consulta sea un poco más elaborada:

```
SELECT Nombre
  FROM Maestros
 WHERE (LEN(ISNULL(@Nombre,'')) = 0 OR Nombre LIKE ('%' + @Nombre + '%'))
   AND (LEN(ISNULL(@Paterno,'')) = 0 OR Paterno LIKE ('%' + @Paterno+ '%'))
   AND (LEN(ISNULL(@Materno,'')) = 0 OR Materno LIKE ('%' + @Materno+ '%'))
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Esto me sirvió mucho. Apliqué la última consulta, por la cuestión que mencionaste de la inyección de código. No sabía lo que comentaste de los parámetros vacíos.

Answer (score 2):

Ya supe que es lo que estaba pasando. Estaba agregando los signos *%* en columnas donde no se necesitaban, como *Paterno* y *Materno*, los estaba tratando como campos de *Nombre*, donde una persona puede tener uno o dos nombres. No sé si será una distracción mía, un pequeño detalle, pero igualmente dejó aquí la consulta como me funcionó:

```
SqlCommand teacherQuery = new SqlCommand("SELECT Nombre FROM MAESTROS WHERE " +
"(Nombre LIKE '%' + @Nombre + '%') OR " +
"(Paterno LIKE @Paterno) OR" +
"(Materno LIKE @Paterno)", conexion);

teacherQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", datos.Nombre);
teacherQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Paterno", datos.APaterno);
```

Aunque debo admitir que sigo sin entender por qué regresaba todos los datos. ¡Muchas gracias! De una vez dejé los paréntesis del OR como me comentaron, más por buena práctica, supongo. Gracias c: